# How to install MySQL for OpenProject?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, openproject

I follow [OpenProject installation](https://community.openproject.org/projects/openproject/wiki/Installation_Windows). My OS is Window-7. When I execute `bundle exec rake db:create:all`, I get as below

```
C:\Sites\openproject>bundle exec rake db:create:all
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
require 'rails/all'... 2.277s
Bundler.require... 5.071s
*** WARNING: You must use ANSICON 1.31 or higher (https://github.com/adoxa/ansic
on/) to get coloured output on Windows
rake aborted!
LoadError: Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-a
dapter` (cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.0/mysql2)

Tasks: TOP => db:create:all
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

That's why, I execute `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` as console said. Now, it is ok as below.

```
C:\Sites\openproject>gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter
Successfully installed activerecord-mysql2-adapter-0.0.3
Parsing documentation for activerecord-mysql2-adapter-0.0.3
1 gem installed
```

I execute `bundle exec rake db:create:all` **again**, I get error **again**

```
C:\Sites\openproject>bundle exec rake db:create:all
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
require 'rails/all'... 2.433s
Bundler.require... 5.055s
*** WARNING: You must use ANSICON 1.31 or higher (https://github.com/adoxa/ansic
on/) to get coloured output on Windows
rake aborted!
LoadError: Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-a
dapter` (cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.0/mysql2)

Tasks: TOP => db:create:all
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

What I need to do? T_T

Comment: When you `bundle exec rake`, you probably also need to `bundle exec gem install`. But that is more of a guess.

Comment: * what happens when you insert `bundle show mysql`
* what ruby version are you using `ruby --version`

Comment: @ulferts Ruby Version 2.0.0,

Comment: @CycDemo OP officially only supports 2.1 but I don't think that this causes the bug. How about the mysql version? Asking because I read of some problems related to mysql gem on Windows.

Comment: @ulferts, According to stack trace, I just know `mysql2/2.0/mysql2`. Thanks support

Comment: @CycDemo, can you please also provide the output of issuing `bundle show mysql`in the OpenProject directory?
Additionally, what does your config/database.yml list as the adapter? Have you taken a look at [this blog](http://www.mohanarun.com/how-to-install-mysql-adapter-ruby-gem-in-windows/)?